# parfor in Matlab using HPC is slower?

Tags: batch-processing, matlab, parfor

I have a problem using `parfor` in Matlab:

-in my laptop using the **local cluster profile** with **12** workers the `parfor` loop is able to substantially reduce the time of computation with respect to the `for` loop;

-in the same laptop but using the **HPC cluster** of my department with **30** workers the `parfor` loop is much much slower than the `for` loop and than the `parfor` loop using the local cluster with 12 workers.

I don't understand why. The number of iterations to solve is above 1000 and each iteration is enough complex to benefit in principle from the `parfor` loop, as proved when I use the local cluster. Maybe there are some steps that I forget to do? To activate the workers I type the command `matlab pool open 30`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many things that could cause this speed difference:

1. If you have file dependencies that are being distributed to the remote workers, that can dramatically increase your overall runtime for computationally simple programs.
2. Assuming no file dependencies, the longer runtimes could be due to the time lost in transferring results back to your local machine from the remote workers.
3. The remote workers could actually be slower, or have less available memory, as is often the case on workstations that double as cluster nodes.

I've seen this a few times, and it's usually #3.

Comment: What do you mean by file dependencies? Could it be the case of a main m-file calling several functions?

Comment: File dependencies are just anything that must be sent to the remote workers in order to complete the task. I honestly don't know if .m files are part of the compiled task or if they must be sent. However, .m files are just text, so they wouldn't matter much. It's the **size** of the data sent that matters. Text files are very small. Now, if your code was processing a large image, and that image must be sent to each worker, that could really slow you down.